# Hacer count en varios campos en una misma ID de una tabla en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

tengo el siguiente problema en consulta de **MYSQL**, la consulta tiene que realizar una consulta **SELECT COUNT** en los campos(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4)buscando los valores **0 (CERO)** y contar cuantos **0 (CEROS)** hay en en TOTAL con un ID_ALUMNOS [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT
CONCAT(saber1,saber2,saber3,saber4) as concatenado FROM planes_alumnos WHERE ID_ALUMNOS=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La *precedencia de operadores* te ayuda al hacer la suma de las negaciones.

```
SELECT !campo1+!campo2+!campo3+!campo4 total
  FROM planes_alumnos
```

Es decir, convierte -implícitamente- a booleano al aplicarle el operador de negación `!`, donde únicamente lo valores 0 negados serán 1. Al sumar esos "unos" obtienes el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Espero haber entendido bien su pregunta.

Recreando la siguiente tabla con los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podría pobrar algo rápido con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT (SUM(campo1 = 0) + SUM(campo2 = 0) + SUM(campo3 = 0)) as Resultado
FROM notas
where id_alumno = 5;
```

Lo que hacemos es hacer que sume 1 si el campo es igual a cero según el id del alumno. Si vas a añadir más campos, solo agregarías un `SUM` más.

Salida:
[image: introducir la descripción]

Por cierto, si posteriormente va a realizar operaciones más complejas y/o agregar dinamismo también puede optar por usar `Cursor`.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Es exactamente el proceso que necesitaba gracias por la ayuda y veo que simplemente fue concatenar las sumas de cada campo

Comment: De nada @Milton. Saludos :D.

Comment: Y por cierto, no estoy concatenando, lo que hago es sumar, ya que lo que devuelve `SUM` es un número.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta query:

```
select 
 id_alumnos
,campo1
,campo2
,campo3
,campo4
,case campo1 when 0 then 1 else 0 end
+case campo2 when 0 then 1 else 0 end
+case campo3 when 0 then 1 else 0 end
+case campo4 when 0 then 1 else 0 end 
total
from planes_alumnos
-- where id_alumnos = 3
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9d4d0/7)

La idea es utilizar un `case` para darle el valor `1` a un campo que tenga `0` y `0` en caso contrario, para justo después sumar todos los campos.